# Android - No ActionBar with API 10

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

i use the ActionBar from the support library to include the actionbar on pre 3.0-devices.

But the problem is, that there is no actionbar showing (with API 10 - on emulator).

With Android 4.2 it works.

I've set this in my manifest:

> android:theme="@style/Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

My styles.xml looks like this:

> ```
> <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
>     <!--
>         Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
>         res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
>         backward-compatibility can go here.
>     -->
> </style>
>     <!-- Application theme. -->
> <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
>     <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
> </style>
> ```

All features works. But there is no actionbar. :( I think this is a Style problem, because there are no exceptions in code.

Answer (score 1):

While your theme looks correct (although most people would prefer to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` for platform independence and a consistent look across all devices), per the [Adding an Action Bar guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding) you must also make sure your activities extend [`ActionBarActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html), rather than `Activity` or `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you for your comment. My activity extends from ActionBarActivity.

Comment: My main activity extends from ActionBarActivity. But i have tabs with the action bar, so the secondary activitys (the activitys in the tabs) extends from "Fragment".